# How can I tell if a file is a valid video stream using RVideo?

Tags: ruby, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to see if a file has a valid video stream using the [RVideo](http://code.google.com/p/rvideo/) library:

read_file.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rvideo'

file_path="/mnt/glusterfs/video/2012/02/04/2012-02-04 1000 CSPAN United Nations Security Council Meeting (337711).mp4"
puts file_path
file = RVideo::Inspector.new(:file => file_path)
```

I get this error:

```
rbennacer@services:~$ ruby read_file.rb 
/mnt/glusterfs/video/2012/02/04/2012-02-04 1000 CSPAN United Nations Security Council Meeting (337711).mp4 
sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Even when I put a backslash before each space character and parenthesis character,  I am getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is coming from the shell.  Rvideo shells out that filepath to `ffmpeg -i`.  So your path is not properly escaped

```
require 'shellwords'
"/mnt/glusterfs/video/2012/02/04/2012-02-04 1000 CSPAN United Nations Security Council Meeting (337711).mp4".shellescape
=> "/mnt/glusterfs/video/2012/02/04/2012-02-04\\ 1000\\ CSPAN\\ United\\ Nations\\ Security\\ Council\\ Meeting\\ \\(337711\\).mp4"
```